# Unable to cd to a folder although I am part of the same group

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a folder, and I can see execution permissions are provided to the `elasticsearch` group so I add myself to this group. Why can't I `cd` to this folder?

```
$ ls -lhd elasti*
drwxr-x--- 2 elasticsearch elasticsearch 4,0K abr 12 17:39 elasticsearch

$ sudo adduser matias elasticsearch
The user `matias' is already a member of `elasticsearch'.

$ cd elasticsearch
bash: cd: elasticsearch: Permission denied
```

Comment: have you opened a new sessions after you added your use to the group? provide the output of the id command

Comment: Are ACL in effect? You can check with `getfacl elasticsearch`.

Comment: A useful command in this kind of situation is `id`, which shows the current user and their group memberships.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is that you added your user to the group in the same shell session as where you try to `cd` into the folder.

For the new group membership to take *effect*, you would have to start a new shell session, or log out and log in again.